# Unable to import Pygame.mixer on an M1 Mac

Tags: python, pygame

When running the code `import pygame.mixer` (or anything else that refers to pygame.mixer) on a 2021 M1 MacBook Air after running the command `python3`, I receive the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame.mixer'`.

What I've tried: reinstalling sdl_mixer, reinstalling sdl2_mixer after editing as per https://github.com/veandco/go-sdl2/issues/299#issuecomment-611681191, reinstalling Pygame after doing that, running the installation of Python at `/usr/bin/python3` and trying the command there, and removing and reinstalling sdl2_mixer normally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the solution is to build pygame from source directly, using the latest pygame version from Github.

See this recent pull request: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/pull/2636

These steps should work (drawn from https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile)

- install homebrew if it isn't already installed
- brew install sdl2 sdl2_gfx sdl2_image sdl2_mixer sdl2_net sdl2_ttf
- brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz
- python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/pygame/pygame.git